# join multiple databases results using ODBC and php

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I have been researching already for couple of days for some solution, but couldn't find anything so far. I'm creating web application to provide some data analysis and current software uses MS access .mdb and once It reaches 1GB, system creates a new database and continues in such way. I need somehow to merge all these databases and make some analysis, but firstly I need to find a good way to apply some query on all of them at the same time. ODBC provides odbc_connect() method, using it I can create multiple connections, but then when I run odbc_exec() I need to specify connection, therefore other databases are left untouched. Question is, how to attach all databases and apply odbc_exec() on all of them. Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Hmmm... You're describing a highly advanced feature that only [major DBMSes offer](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm). Access can hardly cope with more than one simultaneous user. I'm far from being an Office expert (thus I'm only leaving a comment) but I suspect you'll have to query raw data file by file and then either do everything in PHP or dump it somewhere else to perform further analysis.

Comment: Thanks for comment, Im also far away from expert in this field, but maybe you know by any chance, when I get execution result lets say from single database(it will return array) is there any tool to simulate another query on that array?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Based on the link in your comment it seems that Access is a "major DBMS" with at least one "highly advanced feature". (Access has had the ability to create "[linked tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/about-importing-and-linking-data-and-database-objects-HP005241695.aspx)" since at least Access 97.) That said, I think you're right that the OP should dump the Access data into some other database (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, or perhaps the Express editions of SQL Server or Oracle) and do the analysis against that.